# Convert uk phone as a string into valid mobile and landline formats

Tags: php, formatting

I am working on a auto listing website for UK and i have used a field for mobile with max 11 digits as max limit, with no spaces or anything, only 11 digit mobile and landline numbers can be there.

I am looking for a function which displays a number like 0114328929238 coming from database but I want it to displayed in the following way

(01494) 670007
(07763) 786786 
(0843) 3096063

I have the numbers stored in my database field in form of 11 digits such as 
0114328929238

I need to show these numbers in format above and most importantly it should be a valid UK mobile and landline formats.

Pleae help me wiht it.

Comment: Not everyone's from UK. So you need to mention how to check the correctness of numbers. How can your `0114328929238` convert to `(01494) 670007`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$phoneFromDatabase = '01234567890';
$phone = '(' . substr($phoneFromdatabase, 0, 4) . ') ' . substr($phoneFromDatabase, 5);
```